# How to build a programmer's wiki

Tags: documentation, wiki

For years I've missed a wiki so everyone could describe the new tools programmed, the servers where they are running, svn information, the internal rules of programming, how-tos, code samples, etc.
The wiki might be used for the dozen of programmers in the company and the externals.

I've been using a pmwiki (easy install) and now I want a better approach.

What wiki do you use? What plug-ins? Do you think there are better systems than wiki for this?

Comment: What don't you like about pmwiki that you're looking to solve?

Comment: Setting up a group wiki seems like a superuser question.  http://superuser.com/questions/18967/recommendations-for-internal-wiki

Comment: We don't like pmwiki text editor

Answer (score 2):

We're using TWiki for internal dev stuff, and I don't particularly like it. I'd rather use MediaWiki, as that's what Wikipedia uses, and more people are familiar with it.

Comment: MediaWiki is a good all around wiki, but lacks a few things I find incredibly useful for business use / development usage. For example a sane ACL, subscription to changes for sending emails, page-locking so other don't jack with your stuff while you're editing. DokuWiki and TikiWiki do these. I'm sure you could write a plug-in for MediaWiki but these already have those features.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using a TWiki for several years, but it is being retired and replaced by [TRAC](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki).

Wen we started using TWiki I had great hopes, but the requirement for a special markup (like here on SO) never caught on with the management and admin types.

TRAC, as a wiki, is no better in that regard, but it suported by our IT guys and brings more tools for the development process.